# What did I do wrong with this program it throws System.IndexOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    const string CFd = "...\\...\\Duomenys.txt";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int ki, kj;
        int[,] Grafas = new int[10,10];
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(CFd))
        {
            string line;
            string[] parts;
            line = reader.ReadLine();
            ki = int.Parse(line);
            kj = int.Parse(line); 
            for (int i = 0; i < ki; i++)
            {
                line = reader.ReadLine();
                parts = line.Split(' ');
                for (int j = 0; j < kj; j++)
                {
                    Grafas[i,j] = int.Parse(parts[j]); //It throws exception in this line
                }
            }
        }
        //--------------------------
        for (int i = 0; i < ki; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; i < kj; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", Grafas[i,j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I just don't really know what I did qrong and I'm quite new to c#, so if nyone would be nice enough to help it would mean a lot. All I need is for it to read themultidimensional array from file and then print it in console after that I'll try to do everything else it's just that even reading the file doesn't work...

Text file looks like this:

```
5
5
0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 1
```

Found the problem thank you for help everyone

Comment: Read the exception. They aren't just random junk. They tell you what has gone wrong and where...

Comment: I know and I tried I just don't understnd what is the problem that is why I am asking for help it is not like I just want an easy solution I'm just really lost right now...

Comment: So debug.either `Grafas[i,j]` or `parts[j]` is causing a problem. What are the values of `i` and `j`?

Comment: At first they should be zero and then add one until it becomes the numbers written in first 2 line of the file for example I was using 5

Comment: And the lengths of the arrays? Not what you *think* they are. What they actually are...

Comment: Well I think its from 0 to 9

Comment: I specifically said "Not what you *think* they are" ;-) And since you have a 2D array you have 2 dimensions that need to be right...

Comment: Well I tried to define that both demintions would be 10 long

Comment: Heath--do you know how to set a breakpoint and inspect variables?  If not, that is what you need to learn to do so that you can debug problems like this yourself.  Index out of range means you are trying to access something in an array that doesn't exist.  So if the array has 10 elements, trying to access array[10] will throw this exception.  Your code is simply trying to access an element that doesn't exist--i.e., it is counting too high.

Comment: What is in your text file? It could well be that int.Parse creates a value out of bounds of your array.

Comment: Oh so it means the problem is probably with reading those first two values and could you explain me how to inspect values cause I know how to set a breakpoint :)

Comment: It looks like this
5
5
0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 1

Comment: wait it doesnt let me put it in anouther line ill just try to update the question

Comment: Nope I'm really bad at this :(

Comment: Well I found out that program breaks when j reaches  1 :/

Comment: Ok found a prob, ty for help

Comment: Updated my answer below, you don't need the second loop for output, and added some explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the first line in the file contains the correct size of the height **and** width of the two dimensional array?

Also, while printing to the console, your nested for loop should say 
`j < kj` instead of `i < kj`:

```
for (int j = 0; j < kj; j++)
{
    Console.Write("{0} ", Grafas[i,j]);
}
```

**EDIT:** Your text file is using two lines to define the height and width of the array but your code is only reading one line.

Try this instead:

```
line = reader.ReadLine();
ki = int.Parse(line);
line = reader.ReadLine();
kj = int.Parse(line);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line you assign a value to kj.

```
 kj = int.Parse(line);
```

Suppose that value is 50.

Now this loop will iterate 50 times.

```
for (int j = 0; j < kj; j++)
{
      Grafas[i,j] = int.Parse(parts[j]); //It throws exception in this line
}
```

But size of `parts` array is determined by this line.

```
parts = line.Split(' ');
```

So if size of `parts` is 20, the system will throw an error because 50 > 20.

In addition to that, the size of `Grafas[i,j]` is `[10,10]. So if`i`or`j` is greater than 10, it will again throw a similar error.

Hope this helps. You will have to rethink about this logic.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
class Program
{
    const string CFd = "...\\...\\Duomenys.txt";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       int ki, kj;
        int[,] Grafas;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(CFd))
        {
            string line;
            string[] parts;
            ki = int.Parse(reader.ReadLine()); //read first line
            kj = int.Parse(reader.ReadLine()); //read second line
            Grafas = new int[ki, kj]; //define array size
            for (int i = 0; i < ki; i++)
            {
                line = reader.ReadLine();
                parts = line.Split(' ');
                for (int j = 0; j < kj; j++)
                {
                    Grafas[i, j] = int.Parse(parts[j]); //no more exception!
                    Console.Write("{0} ", Grafas[i, j]); //Output here, so no need for second loop.
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

What has changed? We now base the size of the array on the first 2 lines of the text file. Then we parse the results to fill the array.

Output:

```
0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 1
```